# Jenkins credentials not showing when creating docker cloud in jenkins nodes, how to fix that?

Tags: docker, jenkins

This is docker cluod options in Node section of jenkins.

the secret is in jenkins --> system --> global credentails runrestricted

[image: settings]

I add credentails already.
[image: credentials]

But not showing in the drop down.

[image: Not showing]